# Lose focus event in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, I can use the ng-focus directive to know when I have the focus of an input field, but what about when I lose the focus?

Is there any directive for that?

Comment: Lose focus == blur, so `ngBlur`.

Comment: @zeroflagL Ah I wasn't aware that was what blur meant, thanks, you could probably put that as an answer for the record

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The opposite of the `focus` event is the `blur` event. It's fired when an element loses its focus. So what you are looking for is the `ngBlur` directive.

Comment: lose focus and blur are two different things, on page load most of the text boxes will be on blur and the provided event for that  will get triggered on the page load also if i am right.

Comment: @irfanshafi I think you confuse blurred with inactive.